# c++ linux iconv to convert utf-8 to ascii has unknown behaviour

Tags: c++, linux, utf-8, iconv

I have a c++ function that is supposed to convert utf-8 to windows codepage 1252. This function works well for everything that can be converted to ascii.

But if I use chinese characters (for example) 芬 it does not convert it at all so the result in the out buffer (utf8_tmpbuf) is what was in there from before.

```
static void Utf8CharToLatin(char* src, char* dest)
{
  size_t srclen = 1;
  size_t dstlen = 10;

  char source[10];
  strcpy( source, src);
  srclen = strlen(source);
  source[srclen+1] = '\0';

  utf8_tmpbuf[0] = ' ';

  char * pIn = source;
  char * pOut = ( char*)utf8_tmpbuf;

  if (srclen == 0) return;
  srclen++;

  // Convert to Latin
  iconv_t conv = iconv_open("CP1252","UTF-8//TRANSLIT");
  iconv(conv, &pIn, &srclen, &pOut, &dstlen);
  iconv_close(conv);

  sprintf(dest,"%s", utf8_tmpbuf);
  return;
}
```

In this version I have forced utf8_tmpbuf[0] to be a space, so that I can test afterwards that if the codepoint is greater than 127 and the result is a space it is a character that cannot be converted to ascii.

Have anyone else seen this behaviour ?

Comment: For MS-Windows converting to UTF-16 would be better

Comment: This conversion has to be done on c++ on linux.